# htaccess redirect all 404s on a subdomain to subdomain homepage

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404, subdomain

my site, site.com, has several subdomains.
one of these subdomains is go.site.com.
i need all 404 requests on go.site.com to redirect to the subdomain's homepage, which is go.site.com.
i need my primary domain and my other subdomains to not be affected.

```
example 1: go.site.com/abcdefg/ returns a 404 and should redirect to go.site.com
example 2: go.site.com/page/ returns a 200 and should NOT redirect anywhere
example 3: site.com/abcdefg/ returns a 404 and should NOT redirect anywhere
example 4: sub.site.com/abcdefg/ returns a 404 and should NOT redirect anywhere
```

how can i handle this with .htaccess? by the way, it's a wordpress multisite.

Answer (score 1):

You can have this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^go\.site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R]
```

Comment: thanks, but adding this didn't redirect any of my 404s. any other ideas i can try?

Comment: This rule only affects go.site.com URLs.

Comment: but when i visit go.site.com/abcdefg/ from my example above, i get the 404 page. i need that request to redirect to go.site.com

Comment: If this rule is your first rule in root .htaccess of `go.site.com` then you be redirected to `http://go.site.com/`